# Not to forget - Is this a prepositional phrase?

Tags: phrases

> Not to forget that you are wholly in charge of the quality of food
>   that you put into your babys mouth!

I have learned that each sentence needs to contain subject, verb, object, etc. What is a  function of the `not to forget` at the begining of the sentence? Is this some kind of introductory phrase? Which are the other types of phrases in English?

Comment: It's the imperative. _(Be sure) not to forget that..._

Comment: I don't think native speakers use the phrase "Not to forget" in this way.  It should be "Don't forget", "Do not forget", "Let's not forget", "Remember", "Never forget", etc, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a similar idiomatic expression "Not to mention that" which means (more or less) "also":

> I met a great guy at the gym yesterday.  He's smart, he's funny, and **not to mention that** he's a Libra!

"Not to forget" seems like a *made-up* phrase based off of "not to mention".  I understand from context that it means "keep in mind" but I wouldn't call it "standard" English, or use it elsewhere.

As for what to call it, I expect it's an *idiom* of some kind, which adds some emphasis to the sentence but otherwise doesn't significantly affect the meaning.